# Trying to pass two variables in JavaScript popup

Tags: javascript, php

I'm calling the script below, now I need to be able to send two values to `test23.php` like

```
myFunction20(url,url2)
```

Can someone please help?

```
<script>
 function myFunction20(url) {window.open('test23.php?id=' + url, "_blank", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=70,left=50,width=1200,height=500");}</script>
```

PHP Code

```
echo "<td>" .'<a href= javascript:myFunction20("'.$row['Account_Number'].'","'.$row['Account_Number'].'")>'.$row['Name'].'</a>' . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a second key/value pair to the querystring:

```
function myFunction20(url) {
    window.open('test23.php?id=' + url + "&SECOND_KEY=" + "SECOND_KEY_VALUE",
    "_blank", 
    "toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, top=70, left=50, width=1200, height=500");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap up the PHP variables in quotes and pass it your JS function

```
<?php
  $parameter1 = "'" . $row['Account_Number'] . "'";
  $parameter2 = "'" . $row['Account_Number'] . "'";
  echo 
   '<td>
      <a href= javascript:myFunction20(' . $ip . ',' . $id . ')>' . $row["Name"] . '</a> 
    </td>';
```

Your JS function

```
<script>
  function myFunction20(url, url2) {
    window.open('test23.php?id=' + url + '&' + url2, "_blank", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=70,left=50,width=1200,height=500");
  }

</script>
```